# Data isn't write in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, require-once

I have two php files.

Here is one and the code:

```
<?php
require_once('../includes/php.config.db.php');

//here i have a script (xpath) for exctracting data (work 100%)

  $naslov = $data['naslov'];
  $latitude = $data['lat'];
  $longitude = $data['lng'];
  $latitude = (float) $latitude;
  $lin = $data['link'];
  $vreme = $data['vreme'];

  $popust = str_replace ('POPUST','',$data['popust']);
  $firma = $data['firma']; 
  $telefon = $data['telefon'];
  $email = $data['email'];
  $sajt = $data['sajt'];
  $type = 'bar';


  $latitude = (float) $latitude;
  $longitude = (float) $longitude;

//end 

?>
```

The second file is php.config.db.php which i call above:

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass') or die('<p>Nije moguce uspostaviti konekciju sa database serverom!</p>');

mysql_select_db('tablename', $link);

mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

mysql_query("SET COLLATION_CONNECTION='utf8_general_ci'");



function insertNewMarker($name='', $lat='', $lng='', $slika='', $link='', $type='', $popust='', $vaziDo='') {

    if(!empty($name) and !empty($lat) and !empty($lng) and !empty($link)) {

        $name = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($name));



        $sql = "INSERT INTO `markers` (`name`, `lat`, `lng`, `address`, `totolink`, `type`, `popust`, `vaziDo`) <br />

VALUES ('$name', '$lat', '$lng', '$slika', '$link', '$type', '$popust', '$vaziDo')";

        mysql_query($sql) or print "<p>Error in SQL Statement ($sql):<br />". mysql_error() .'</p>';

    }

    else {

        print "<p>Polja 'name', 'lat' i 'lng' ne smiju biti prazna!<br />Vi ste uneli <br />Name:$name<br />Lat:$lat<br />Lng:$lng</p>";

    }

}

?>
```

but when i start php file only i get a white screen without error and my database is empty. WHY? (sorry for my english)

Comment: set display_errors value to show errors, also error_reporting function.

Comment: What does basic debugging say? Where are you calling `insertNewMarker()`?

Comment: Yes it looks like you never call insertnewmarker

Comment: fyi. your code could be susceptible to sql injection.

Comment: Also make sure that the path used in the `require_once` is valid - `if (is_file('../includes/php.config.db.php') && is_readable('../includes/php.config.db.php')) require_once('../includes/php.config.db.php'); else die('Require path is invalid...');`

Comment: Imagine coming to the car mechanic and saying "Hi, this is my car, it won't run. Here are the tires and here's the wheel. I also have a turbo charger and it works 100% however I left that and the engine at home. Also, I never turn the engine on. WHAT'S THE PROBLEM?!". It's really not THAT hard to notice what's wrong before going to SO asking for help with trivial stuff that's been answered over and over and over and over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `<br/>` tag in your SQL INSERT statement

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `markers` (`name`, `lat`, `lng`, `address`, `totolink`, `type`, `popust`, `vaziDo`) <br />

VALUES ('$name', '$lat', '$lng', '$slika', '$link', '$type', '$popust', '$vaziDo')";
```

It should be something like:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `markers` (`name`, `lat`, `lng`, `address`, `totolink`, `type`, `popust`, `vaziDo`) VALUES ('$name', '$lat', '$lng', '$slika', '$link', '$type', '$popust', '$vaziDo')";
```

Comment: if that was true it would at least show an error since it catches the error with a print error

Comment: Well, as it was stated in a different comment, it looks as though the function that includes this call is never, itself, called.